# Simple .check(matches(isDisplayed())) fails with "Cannot resolve method 'matches(Matcher<View>)'."

Tags: android, android-espresso

When running some test with this line:  `onView(withId(R.id.topTextView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

I get this error:

`Cannot resolve method 'matches(Matcher<View>)'`

I can't find any matches online why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After searching on this forever and not finding answers... I about gave up and started reworking my file.

I happened to noticed I had this import:

`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.matches;`

Instead of...

`import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;`

For the love of... I can't believe I wasted so much time on that... I'm only putting this up here in hopes of someone else avoiding wasting so much time on such a silly problem. :o

End advice, if there are no answers for your quoted error, check your imports.

Comment: You saved me from hours of wasting time with this :)